# Function keys not working

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, function-keys, msi

I have bought a new MSI PS63 Modern 8RD laptop.
It is a 15" laptop with a compact keyboard.

The problem here is that I can't find a way to get my function keys to work.

I have the brightness and volume keys on the arrows and they are working properly, but the other function keys which are placed on the F's are not working. *I.e <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> triggers airplane mode, but it does not seem to work!!*

Hardware & software specifications:

- [MSI PS63 Modern 8RD](https://www.msi.com/Content-Creation/PS63-MODERN-8RX)
- Compact keyboard
- Ubuntu 18.04.3 64-bit

Comment: Enter BIOS and check if there is any option to modify Fn keys behaviour. (My BIOS does have one.)

Comment: @Quasímodo the Fn is indeed working, as I mentioned with the brightness and volume, but it does not work with the other keys which are places on the F's

Comment: Please run `xev` and provide the output of the `F10` and of the `Fn+F10` keys.

Comment: @Quasímodo
output for `F10`:
`KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x1b0, subw 0x0, time 1192345, (161,-21), root:(258,137),
    state 0x0, keycode 76 (keysym 0xffc7, F10), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False`
output for `Fn+F10`:
No ouput (not detected)

Comment: Switch to a TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F1, Ctrl-Alt-F2, ..., Ctrl-Alt-F6, whichever works), authenticate, run `showkey`, repeat the test for `F10` and `Fn+F10`. Then come back to X session with Ctrl-Alt-F1 (or maybe Ctrl-Alt-F7) and provide the output.

Comment: @Quasímodo output for `F10`: `keycode 68 press/release`. And again no output for `Fn+F10`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102666/discussion-between-ahmedisam-and-quasimodo).

Answer (score 0):

Kernel above 5.0 could manage your function keys.

You could also try  acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009" in older kernel